# A Graphics Card for an excellent experience with a Valve Index VR

Tags: graphics-cards, vr-headset

What Graphics Card (GPU) would give me the best bang for the buck to use with a Valve Index VR Headset?

I don't want to spend more money than I need, but I don't want the VR experience to suffer either.

Would I notice any difference between the Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 and the RTX 2070?
Or would a Graphics Card like [Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2060 OC Rev2 HDMI 3xDP 6GB](https://www.gigabyte.com/Graphics-Card/GV-N2060OC-6GD-rev-20#kf) do?

Any tips from someone with experience from using a Valve Index VR Headset with any  of these graphics cards?

Comment: Graphics card requirements depend more on the games you want to run, and the settings you use. The display you need to drive is of secondary concern. Also, knowing more about the rest of the system would be helpful, in order to ensure compatibility and avoid bottlenecks elsewhere.

Comment: The "recommended system requirements" will tell you all you need to know if you have a game in mind already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**=> Nvidia RTX 3060 Ti**

I am using it, excellent in gaming and decent enough for VR experience.